# Trouble with understanding classes in C++

Tags: c++, class

I've got a class and a namespace, and I need to access data of the class from a different file.
Example:

```
namespace A {
   struct SMS{
       string id;
       Messages msg; //(an array of strings)
   };
}

class Users{
public:
//ALL THE FUNCTIONS HERE TO MANAGE THE USER
private:

struct User{
       string id_user;
       SMS sms;
       };
};
```

So now I want to access `sms` and the array in it, but I can't find a way.
Is it supposed to be something like this?

```
User ada_lovelace;
return ada_lovelace.sms.msg[1];
```

or:

```
return ada_lovelace.A::sms.msg[1];?
```

Comment: `A::sms` would look for `sms` in `A`.

Comment: You need to show a more complete version of `Users`.  Right now all we know is `User` contains a private struct.

Comment: As long as you declare the user `A::User ada_lovelace;`, you should be able to access `ada_lovelace.sms.msg[1];`. Furthermore, C++ uses the keyword `class`, not `Class`.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile so you really need to make that happen before trying to access members.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends where are you going to define and use `ada_lovelace`. If your are going to declare it in one of the methods of class `Users` or as a member of the class, you should define User as:

```
struct User{
   string id_user;
   A::SMS sms;
   };
```

and you should be able to use

```
return ada_lovelace.sms.msg[1];
```

However, if you want to use `ada_lovelace` ouside of class `Users`, you must define `User`as public and create the object like this:

```
Users::User ada_lovelace;
```

Answer (score -2):

Check the implementation below

```
namespace A {
   struct SMS{
       string id;
       Messages msg; //(an array of strings)
   };
}

//Namespace A ends here so if you want to use SMS in the class u need to mention it as A::SMS sms

class Users{
public:
//ALL THE FUNCTIONS HERE TO MANAGE THE USER
private:

struct User{
       string id_user;
       A::SMS sms; // Corrected here ------------
       };
};
```